# why is it showing "error: not well-formed (invalid token)." in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I recently downloaded android studio. there i saw an error was showing
"error: not well-formed (invalid token)." i don't understand why, but here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/car"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</RelativeLayout>
```

i am tring since 2-3 hours and any help will be appreciated.
pls help what should i do now???

Comment: Hello, welcome to S.O. where in this layout is the error shown? Have you tried `invalidate caches and restart` in Android Studio? Have you tried creating a new XML layout? Is the XML located in the correct res/layout folder?

Comment: well, When i got this problem, I tried searching it on Stack overflow, and after a lots of researching, i finally got a answer and problem is solved. sorry for not letting anyone. But thnx for the advice.